# Creating Overall RAG status in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have three RAG status build with logic. Now my requirement is to create overall RAG over them. There are different department filters applied on three RAG status. Now I want to implement overall RAG on below condition.
Please note - Below - G= Green, A=Amber and R=Red

a.  G-G-G = G

b.  G-G-A = G

c.  G-A-A = G

d.  A-A-A = A

e.  G-G-R = R

f.  G-R-R = R

g.  R-R-R = R

Please suggest

Below image shows how we are working for RAG1

[1]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqJYQ.jpg)

[This image shows dashboard having three RAG and above all on left is overall RAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqJYQ.jpg)

Considering situation a.    G-G-G = G
IF RAG1 returns G AND RAG2 returns G AND RAG3 returns G then over all RAG will be G(Green)

Now, Considering situation d.   A-A-A = A
IF RAG1 returns A AND RAG2 returns A AND RAG3 returns A then over all RAG will be A(Amber)

Now, Considering situation e.   G-G-R = R
IF RAG1 returns G AND RAG2 returns G AND RAG3 returns R then over all RAG will be R(Red)

Comment: What logic are you using to come up with the RHS?

Comment: Let me explain my scenerio in detail.
I have three RAG status named RAG1, RAG2, RAG3
For each of these three RAGs i have multiple Department Codes. For instance for RAG1 i have to use DeptCode1, 2 and for RAG2 i have to use DeptCode3 and for RAG3 i have DeptCode4,5
So now i have three sheets created with DeptCode filter over them like if Sum(Amount)>90 RAG is Green(G)
else if Sum(Amount)>60 and <=90 RAG is Amber(A)
else RAG is Red(R)
I have created three dimensions that calculates status for displaying in all three sheets
Now i need new sheet that will create overall RAG depending on it

Comment: RAG1 - RAG2 - RAG3 = Overall RAG

Comment: Do you have a order preference for RAG1 RAG2 RAG3?
or are you simply looking to concatenate the three?

It would be helpful if you could edit the post with screenshots of what you have and what you are looking for

Comment: I have edited the question with attached screenshot. No there is no order of RAG, its just the combination which will give result. For instance if situation is A-A-R it really doesnt matter whether R is RAG1 or RAG2 or RAG3, it will simply make overall RAG as RED(R)

Comment: So, A-A-R = R implies that R takes precedence over A. This is a type of ordering

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

This might be a possible solution,

Recode the labels 'A', 'G' and 'R' as 0,1,3 (numeric) respectively.

Now create a column which will be a sum of the recoded columns,
example, if the sequence is AGR, then new_col = 0+1+3 = 4

Now, create a calculated field (CF) with the following logic,

```
if new_col >0 & new_col <= 3 then 'G'
else if new_col > 3 then 'R'
else 'A'
```

And then use this calculated field to use as color indicator.